# Update record exception occurred using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the record and an exception is being thrown. Are there any errors with this code?

```
try
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Common.GetDBConnectionString()))
   {
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCommand cmd =
                        new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Tb_Patient SET Name = @PatientName, Age = @PatientAge, Contact = @PatientContact, Date = @PatientDate, Occupation = @PatientOccupation, Gender = @PatientGender " +
                            " WHERE Id=@SetVForText", conn))
      {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SetVForText);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtage.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtcontact.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtdate.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", txtoccupation.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender",comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() );

         int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Update successfully");

         //rows number of record got updated
      }
   }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Updation failed"+ex);
}
```

Comment: What is the error/exception?

Comment: you are adding most of the parameters. like  PatientName  PatientContact  etc..

Comment: Have you opened the connection to the database..?? This might be one of the reason. try to change the field 'Date', it always cause some confusions and due to that some unavoidable exceptions. Hope it helps

Comment: there is a big exception in a very big box............:(

Comment: Jeeez... Set a breakpoint in the `catch` block and tell us the exception message! Point the mouse to `ex` and tell us the error message. Alternatively, change `+ex` to `+ex.Message` and run again.

Comment: @SidraAbbasi Set a Breakpoint on 'ex' - use F9, run the project as usual get the exception and paste on your question.

Comment: how ca i get this exception......:(

Answer (score 0):

I'd say make sure to convert `txtdate.Text` to a valid `DateTime`. This is the most probably cause for update errors. Also, you need to use the *parameter names*  in `AddWithValue`, not the *column name*!

Even though to some degree conversion takes place, you should generally make sure to pass the correct data types in the command parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you must have same names for parameters:

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientName", txtname.Text);

instead of

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);

Answer (score 0):

These are all wrong.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SetVForText);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtage.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtcontact.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtdate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", txtoccupation.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender",comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() );
```

You are using the name of the field like it was the name of the parameters. The parameters are named differently

```
@PatientName,@PatientAge,@PatientContact,@PatientDate,
@PatientOccupation,@PatientGender @SetVForText
```

Therefore your AddWithValue calls should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SetVForText", SetVForText);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientName", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientAge", txtage.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientContact", txtcontact.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientDate", txtdate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientOccupation", txtoccupation.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientGender",comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() );
```

Moreover, from your question is not possible to identify the correct datatype for the parameters. As written every field in the datatable should be of varchar/nvarchar datatype because your are passing strings to AddWithValue with the possible exception of `SetVForText`

Comment: All parameters have string datatype except date(TimeDate) and SetVForText(int).

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError, System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning,System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run, etc.......:(

Comment: you have a problem on your connection, check your connection string.

Comment: Data Source=SIDRA-PC; Initial Catalog=DATABASE; Integrated Security=True;

Comment: @ is my connection string and this string works while inserting data.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be help you. in database allow null value to date time column and send date from text box as 'mm/dd/yyyy' format

```
    try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Common.GetDBConnectionString()))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    DateTime? Date;
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(txtdate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                               out Date);

                    if (Date == Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"))
                        Date = null;

                    using (SqlCommand cmd =
                                      new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Tb_Patient SET Name = @Name, Age = @Age, Contact = @Contact, Date = @Date, Occupation = @Occupation, Gender = @Gender " +
                                          " WHERE Id=@SetVForText", conn))
                    {


                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", SetVForText);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtname.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtage.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", txtcontact.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", txtoccupation.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

                        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Update successfully");

                        //rows number of record got updated
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Updation failed" + ex);
            }
```

Comment: if your connection is proper than may be date conversion throw an exception. just try this code

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: are you send the text value as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: post your date textbox value

Comment: 32/52/ 13 this z 3/25/2013